How to Fix Slow Checkout Process in Magento 2?
I’ve noticed that the checkout process on my Magento 2 store is slower than expected. I’ve already checked basic configurations and server performance but haven’t found a significant improvement.
Could anyone suggest:

Performance Tuning: Specific settings or configurations to optimize the checkout speed?

Extensions: Are there any extensions that could help enhance checkout performance?

Debugging: Tools or methods to identify and resolve bottlenecks in the checkout process?


Any insights or advice would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks!
Best,
Arthi.

For the speed up, you can also check any third party extension increase load in checkout.


U can check if full-page cache is enable.

If you're using Elasticsearch, consider switching to ElasticSuite for better performance in searches and indexing, which could indirectly improve checkout speed by reducing search-related bottlenecks.

Minify and Bundle JavaScript/CSS

If use new relic there can check requests that are slowed, with this can map which modules thrid-party are impacting


